# ListView Command Set extension - What are supported values for "RegistrationId" and "RegistrationType" in <Elements><CustomAction>?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I would like to create a ListView Command Set Extension for modern views using a SharePoint Framework solution.  Ideally I would be able to apply my "Custom Actions" only to specific list types or content types.  This could be done using Classic Custom Actions.

What are the supported values for "RegistrationId" and "RegistrationType" in the element manifest?

This tutorial indicates you can use "100" or "101" for RegistrationId and "List" for RegistrationType: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api.

Are there more possibilities?  Is there documentation for precisely what is supported for the latest SPFx version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegistrationId` is for `RegistrationType` "List" the base list template, so you can use that to target specific list types. 100 is a generic list, 101 is a document library.

For `RegistrationType`, only **List** is supported for now.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that 100 is for generic list and 101 is for document library.  My question is what other values can I specify? For example, can I use 104 for an Announcements list?  Can I use the ID for my own custom list definition? etc. Also, can you point me to any documentation that is more explicit than the link I included.

Comment: Yes you can use any valid list type id, including your own. The link you have is the official documentation for SPFx. You can read more about the CustomAction element [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/customaction-element), but it won't do much good as only the List is supported in SPFx...